# Redirigir desde un wordpress a otro pasando una variable

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Tengo un dominio con una pagina wordpress, despues de una accion por parte del usuario, debo enviar el id de usuario a otra pagina tambien con wordpress en el subdominio del primero (esto no se si vale para algo), y que muestre esta segunda pagina con el dato enviado, habia pensado enviarlo con $_post, pero la verdad no tengo claro como hacerlo.

Redirigir desde la primera por hooks es sencillo, pero como envio el dato, y donde lo recibo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Envíalo con `GET`, por ejemplo: `http://www.sitio_wp_2.com?uid=58`. No será lo más lindo, pero funciona. De hecho esa forma es muy usada para, por ejemplo, registrar el medio que usó una persona para entrar a una página (`direccion.com?medium=facebook`, twitter, whatsapp, etc...)

Comment: Si, pero si voy a usar para pasar información privada, prefiero post

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar por post, el link del primer WordPress debería ser en realidad un form con un input oculto en el cuál indicas el valor que quieres enviar y el botón (o disparador) que ejecuta el submit. Entonces hará el envío hacia el segundo WordPress.

```
<form action="http://wordpress2.com/pagina" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" value="valor" name="WP1_form" />
 <button type="submit">
</form>
```

En el WordPress de destino yo crearía un acción en el wp_head para ver si hemos recibido un formulario del primer WordPress. Grosso modo, algo así:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_head','formWP1Check');
function formWP1Check()
{
  if((isset($_POST))&&(isset($_POST['WP1_form']))&&(validarValor($_POST['WP1_form'])))
  {
    acciones();
  }
}
```

Esto si fuera para cualquier página. Sino se podría poner el código en el template de la página concreta que desees que sea la de destino.

Espero que te sirva la idea...

Comment: Gracias, creo que si me valdra